# change default background of linear layout

Tags: android

In my XML file, I have 1 linear layout, in that 2 Child linear layouts. I have assigned
'tools:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"' in all 3 layouts.
The background has changed. I can see it in preview of android studio. But when I deploy it on my phone, background remains the same default grey color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tools:background` will *only* display in the preview. It's not actually setting anything on the View, and is used so the preview can show an example property.

Use `android:background`.

Answer (score 0):

As [TheWanderer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52211278/4779042) said, `tools:background` make preview changes and will be visible only in the preview. There are more attributes for the preview. For example `tools:text="Something"` for any textView will show you `Something` in the textView only for preview. So you will be able to see how it will look in preview, yet in release there won't be any placeholder text. So it is useful thing to have.